# add geometry from vertex and vertex nromal

Tags: three.js

I load a model with vertex and vertex nromal,

```
for (var i = 0, vindex = 0; i < triangle.length; i++, vindex += 3) {

            x = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('x1').value);
            y = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('y1').value);
            z = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('z1').value);
            this.geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x * scale + this.translateVector.x, y * scale + this.translateVector.y, z * scale + this.translateVector.z));

            x = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('x2').value);
            y = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('y2').value);
            z = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('z2').value);
            this.geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x * scale + this.translateVector.x, y * scale + this.translateVector.y, z * scale + this.translateVector.z));

            x = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('x3').value);
            y = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('y3').value);
            z = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('z3').value);
            this.geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x * scale + this.translateVector.x, y * scale + this.translateVector.y, z * scale + this.translateVector.z));

            var face = new THREE.Face3(vindex, vindex + 1, vindex + 2);
            face.color.setHex(this.faceColor || this.defaultcolor);
            face.vertexNormals = [];

            nx = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('nx1').value);
            ny = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('ny1').value);
            nz = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('nz1').value);
            face.vertexNormals.push(new THREE.Vector3(-nx, -ny, -nz));

            nx1 = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('nx2').value);
            ny1 = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('ny2').value);
            nz1 = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('nz2').value);
            face.vertexNormals.push(new THREE.Vector3(-nx1, -ny1, -nz1));

            nx2 = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('nx3').value);
            ny2 = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('ny3').value);
            nz2 = parseFloat(triangle[i].attributes.getNamedItem('nz3').value);
            face.vertexNormals.push(new THREE.Vector3(-nx2, -ny2, -nz2));

            face.normal.set((nx + nx1 + nx2) / 3, (ny + ny1 + ny2) / 3,(nz + nz1 + nz2) / 3);

            this.geometry.faces.push(face);
            }

this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: true , opacity: 1, transparent: 0 });

        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
        this.mesh.name = this.id;

        this.mesh.updateMatrix();
        this.mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

        scene.add(this.mesh);
```

the house below, front face is invisible, so front wall and left wall is invisible, we can see through the inside of house, but I want it to show all walls and not see through, could anyone help me?

[image]

after I change to Lambert material it still show house inside, I've tried, cw,ccw, or invert index of  vertex, invert normal. could any body help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is possible there is something wrong with the face UV's. try making the material applied doublesided.

Answer (score 0):

seems find the answer.

that's because part of the house model position.z < 0, and camera's near < 0, maybe three.js z-buffer clear negative = 0, z-buffer determines the sheltery relation.